# "Bad weather doesn't exist" vs. "The bad weather doesn't exist"

Tags: grammaticality, articles

Should it be:

> Bad weather doesn't exist.

or

> *The* bad weather doesn't exist.

Comment: I have a feeling you're trying to translate "у природы нет плохой погоды"...

Comment: that's absolutely right! :)

Comment: In that case, you should really visit [our chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95/english-language-and-usage). I would post an answer right here right now, but that would be blatantly off-topic. (The main site is not a translation service; but the chat often is. And there are a few people with sufficient command of Russian there.)

Comment: Thank you, I honestly didn't pay attention to the chat room!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean. Certainly bad weather *does* exist, so you could only be talking about an ideal place on the earth, if there is one, where it doesn't. So if you were talking about such a place (real or imagined), you could say

> Bad weather doesn't exist.

But if you were referring to some specific spate of bad weather that was expected but didn't arrive, you could say

> The bad weather doesn't exist.

But it would be more likely to say

> The bad weather didn't happen.

Comment: You know, I was SURE it didn't require any article. But then, thinking about it, I started to become less sure. So I was thinking, and maybe you confirmed so, here we have the rule "specific vs. non-specific"?

Comment: @Alenanno: Yes, it is about specific vs. non-specific conditions.

Comment: I took it to mean that weather is neither good or bad, it just is.  If you are talking about a particular spate of weather, it seems odd to use the verb 'exist'.  I can't explain it... anyway, the simple answer is that it's variant one.

Comment: I mean that it doesn't matter, whether it rains, snows, whether it's sunny, cloudy or stormy, it's silly to complain about it. I wanted to say that all types of the weather could be good for different people at different times.

Comment: I would note that the reason for this difference is that *the* signals that its referent is already known (it's in the discourse). For how this works, see [anaphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_(linguistics)). Sans *the*, *weather* might be considered a natural kind term, such as *water* or *lions*, which refers to a whole class of objects or a typical member of this class. I am not personally sold on natural kinds, but you might find the theories enlightening.

Comment: @Valentina: *Bad weather* will do what you want, but what about: *there is no weather either good or bad but thinking makes it so*? :^)