# What weather! What a pity! - phrases with and without article - why?

Tags: phrases, articles, exclamations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any simple rules for article usage (“a” vs “the” vs none)](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/are-there-any-simple-rules-for-article-usage-a-vs-the-vs-none)
>   [‘… the weather’ vs. ‘… weather’](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65896/the-weather-vs-weather)
>   [“Bad weather doesn't exist” vs. “The bad weather doesn't exist”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22846/bad-weather-doesnt-exist-vs-the-bad-weather-doesnt-exist)

I've been learning English for over 10 years now and still don't understand the rules for using articles in phrases like:

- What weather!
- What a pity!

Why does one have an article and the other one doesn't. In both phrases we are dealing with abstract, uncountable nouns.

Comment: Very good question. I'll lay odds that your native language is one without articles :) They are notoriously hard to pin down. I have the opposite problem with my Polish, adding demonstratives where I would put articles.

Answer (score 3):

Look closer at the dictionary. Here's a quote from NOAD:

> 1. the feeling of sorrow and compassion caused by the suffering and misfortunes of others: *her voice was full of pity.*
> 2. [in singular] a cause for regret or disappointment:
>    *what a pity we can't be friends.*

In your second sentence – *what a pity!* – the word *pity* is being used in the sense of Meaning #2; hence, an article is used.

I don't know if this would answer your question under *all* circumstances, but, in this instance, the root cause of the confusion is one word having multiple meanings, and different grammatical rules for how  the word is used in each of those senses.

Comment: And contrariwise you have to really reach to come up with a context in which "**a** weather" would be appropriate. (Aside, it appears, from an Oregon indie band named "A Weather").

Answer (score 0):

The use articles in exclamative utterances is no different from the use of articles elsewhere. *A* occurs before *pity*, because *pity*, as J.R.’s reference shows, is used here as a countable noun. *Weather* is almost always uncountable, and so cannot be preceded by the indefinite article.